# Sorting Rows in Excel with a VBA Macro. It worked, except for the last cell of every row

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

So I'm sorting this Excel worksheet in rows alphabetically, avoiding the first few columns. This is my code. Somehow it worked perfectly, sorting rows that go from maybe 20 or 30 cells, to ones with hundreds. Each row has a different number of cells. But it sorted every cell except the last one. The last cell is some random one that comes after the ones beginning in "z", but starts with say, a "P", or an "L".

Here's my code:

```
Sub SortRows()

Dim lngIndex As Long
Dim strArray(9 To 11000) As String
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet, rng As Range

Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Page1")
Set rng = sht.Range("J10:UN10")

intCounter = 1

For lngIndex = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)

    intCounter = intCounter + 1
    strArray(lngIndex) = intCounter

    With sht.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
           Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange rng
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Tested your code and it works fine.  What do you mean by the last cell?  Last cell of every row?  The very last cell?  Please clarify what you mean by "The last cell is some random one that comes after the ones beginning in "z", but starts with say, a "P", or an "L"."  Some expected result vs current result (screenshot) will helps too

Comment: Let's say we have 5 rows with a letter in each cell:

AGJKEO
FODIUT
KGJRUT
GJROIT
DNELFH

I run the sort, and it sorts the first 4 characters/cells for each row, but doesn't include the last cell of each row in the sort, so it ends up like this:

AEGJKO
DFIOUT
GJKRUT
GIJROT
DEFLNH

Comment: Your code on sorting works fine.  chances are your Range does not include the last cell.  Do something like when you select your range, BOLD them / put colorindex on cells, to check if the Range does include every cells on the row

Comment: The range goes really far beyond the end of the rows. Should have mentioned this, sorry:
Every row is a different length, so some are 20 cells and some are 300, but the range goes at least ten cells beyond the end of the longest row.

Comment: Check your UBound(strArray) value, I suspect it goes to your length - 1 cell instead of your last cell.  Hint: Try adding Option Explicit at the very top of your code, like row 1

Comment: I've added Option Explicit at the top.

I'm not sure what you mean as far as checking the strArray value? I have 10049 rows, so I just ran it through 11000 rows to be safe initially, and I was starting with row 9 to skip a few rows I had done manually:
    Dim strArray(9 To 11000) As String

I would think it would be the range rather than the strArray?
But then my starting range is J10:UN10, and the last column being used is actually KZ, so UN goes very far beyond that one:
    Set rng = sht.Range("J10:UN10")

Comment: I was suspecting that your sort's range excluding the very last element, but I was wrong.  So my new questions will be: does it happens to all rows, or starting to happening somewhere down the sheet?  What Excel version you are using?  Also, it will be great if I can get hold of your data sample, cause again it works completely fine here.

Comment: Excel for Mac 2011, Version 14.3.9 (131030)

I would share it but it's sensitive customer data unfortunately...

Yes, it happens to all rows from the first one on.

Comment: Noted, instead of me retrieving the data, how about you put up random data to test? Just do a row or 2 with random data, do not copy and paste from those real one.  use a different worksheet.  I am trying to see / eliminate the possible error coming from the data itself (space, ascii character, etc).  Meanwhile you can run through the code using function key F8 to check each step of the macro

Comment: Ah yes! It works fine for this new sheet, which I used entirely new but similar content for, with a different length for each row.

So if it's working fine on another sheet, then what could it be?

Comment: I am not entirely sure as well, it could be locked cells, something with your original data, or even some unknown bugs.  Now that it works fine with a new sheets, I would suggest you move everything to a new sheet or even a new workbook.

I will give an answer so you can accept and close this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested your code and it works fine.  Try put codes into a new worksheet and test.

Comment: Hey Alex, I tried copying and pasting the whole thing to a new workbook, which didn't work. So I copied just one line to a new workbook, with only the cells that I'm trying to sort, and it's still giving me the same issue. I saved the one with just one line so I can send that to you as a sample so you can see what I'm talking about. How can I share it with you?

Comment: Ok, looks like the problem does comes from your data.  could you please send your file to my email:  Hatfield.alex.2014@gmail.com?